# select box jquery transition not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use this: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/

to add a transition by default to my select-box.

This is the bit of JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $("SELECT").selectBox()
    $("SELECT").click( function() { 
        $("SELECT").selectBox('settings', { 
            'menuTransition': 'slide',
            'menuSpeed' : 'fast' 
        });
    });

});
```

I can't seem to make it slide by default. What am I doing wrong? I was able to get it to work by including a separate button exactly like in the demo page. But I want it to use the slide animation by default and can't see/figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selectBox` plugin looked interesting so I tried it out and I believe your issue is that you are trying to dynamically set the transition type to `slide` but you want to create the `selectBox` with different settings than the default ones, try this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("SELECT").selectBox({
        menuTransition : 'slide',
        menuSpeed      : 'fast'
    });
});
```

Here is a working example of this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/APzDJ/

Comment: thank you I didn't know you needed to put the { in the selectbox parameters. Also I thought you needed a .click and also I thought that 'settings' was needed. How did you know that is how you set the default settings?

Comment: @Sackling If you go to the documentation ( http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-selectBox/jquery.selectBox.js ) then you can see the different methods of creating and updating a `selectBox` instance, at the top of the file is this line: `To create: $("SELECT").selectBox([settings]);`. The brackets come in as they are part of the JavaScript object declaration (`{` == `start object` && `}` == `end object`).